# Storybook - Can't resolve 'generated-stories-entry.cjs' / Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Tags: reactjs, webpack, storybook

After [installing and configuring Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/install) on my Next.js application and running `build-storybook` I am receiving the following error.

*Note*: I am using npm version `8.19.1`. The project is written in Typescript.

```
> msun@0.1.0 storybook:build
> build-storybook

info @storybook/react v6.5.13
info 
info => Cleaning outputDir: /Users/msun/Documents/msun/storybook-static
info => Loading presets
info => Compiling manager..
info => Compiling preview..
info Addon-docs: using MDX1
info => Using PostCSS preset with postcss@8.4.19
info => Using default Webpack5 setup
ERR! => Failed to build the preview
ERR! Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs' in '/Users/msun/Documents/msun'
65% building 14/14 entries 18/18 dependencies 2/6 modulesinfo => Manager built (7.26 s)
ERR! ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs' in '/Users/msun/Documents/msun'
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2016:28
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:798:13
ERR!     at eval (eval at create (/Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:10:1)
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:270:22
ERR!     at eval (eval at create (/Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:434:22
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:116:11
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:670:25
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:855:8
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:975:5
ERR!  ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs' in '/Users/msun/Documents/msun'
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2016:28
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:798:13
ERR!     at eval (eval at create (/Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:10:1)
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:270:22
ERR!     at eval (eval at create (/Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:434:22
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:116:11
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:670:25
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:855:8
ERR!     at /Users/msun/Documents/msun/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:975:5
ERR! resolve '/Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs' in '/Users/msun/Documents/msun'
ERR!   using description file: /Users/msun/Documents/msun/package.json (relative path: .)
ERR!     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!     root path /Users/msun/Documents/msun
ERR!       using description file: /Users/msun/Documents/msun/package.json (relative path: ./Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs)
ERR!         no extension
ERR!           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!           /Users/msun/Documents/msun/Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs doesn't exist
ERR!         .mjs
ERR!           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!           /Users/msun/Documents/msun/Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs.mjs doesn't exist
ERR!         .js
ERR!           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!           /Users/msun/Documents/msun/Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs.js doesn't exist
ERR!         .jsx
ERR!           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!           /Users/msun/Documents/msun/Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs.jsx doesn't exist
ERR!         .ts
ERR!           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!           /Users/msun/Documents/msun/Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs.ts doesn't exist
ERR!         .tsx
ERR!           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!           /Users/msun/Documents/msun/Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs.tsx doesn't exist
ERR!         .json
ERR!           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!           /Users/msun/Documents/msun/Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs.json doesn't exist
ERR!         .cjs
ERR!           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!           /Users/msun/Documents/msun/Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs.cjs doesn't exist
ERR!         as directory
ERR!           /Users/msun/Documents/msun/Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs doesn't exist
ERR!     using description file: /Users/msun/Documents/msun/package.json (relative path: ./generated-stories-entry.cjs)
ERR!       no extension
ERR!         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!         /Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs doesn't exist
ERR!       .mjs
ERR!         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!         /Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs.mjs doesn't exist
ERR!       .js
ERR!         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!         /Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs.js doesn't exist
ERR!       .jsx
ERR!         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!         /Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs.jsx doesn't exist
ERR!       .ts
ERR!         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!         /Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs.ts doesn't exist
ERR!       .tsx
ERR!         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!         /Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs.tsx doesn't exist
ERR!       .json
ERR!         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!         /Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs.json doesn't exist
ERR!       .cjs
ERR!         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
ERR!         /Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs.cjs doesn't exist
ERR!       as directory
ERR!         /Users/msun/Documents/msun/generated-stories-entry.cjs doesn't exist
info => Loading presets
npm notice 
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.1 -> 9.1.2
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.1.2
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@9.1.2 to update!
npm notice
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to the maintainer of Storybook](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/19927#issuecomment-1324075415), there was a recent release of [`enhanced-resolve`](https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/releases/tag/v5.11.0) (a dependency of Storybook) which ended up breaking Storybook installations that use Webpack. You might be experiencing this issue if you 1) recently installed a fresh Storybook, 2) do not use package lock files, or 3) deleted your package lock files and ran `install`.

### Workaround

[Pending a permanent fix](https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/issues/362), a temporary workaround involves pinning `enchanced-resolve` to the latest working version `5.10.0`.

**Add the following line to your `package.json`. Delete `node_modules` and re-install.**

##### npm

```json
// package.json
{
  "overrides": {
    "enhanced-resolve": "5.10.0"
  }
}
```

*Note*: You may have to upgrade to the latest npm for the override to work. `npm install -g npm@latest`

##### Yarn

```json
// package.json
{
  "resolutions": {
    "enhanced-resolve": "5.10.0"
  }
}
```

##### pnpm

```json
// package.json
{
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "enhanced-resolve": "5.10.0"
    }
  }
}
```

#### `warning Resolution field "enhanced-resolve@5.10.0" is incompatible with requested version "enhanced-resolve@x.y.z"`

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/19927#issuecomment-1324360068), a global override may be problematic for projects with dependencies that depend on a different version of `enhanced-resolve`. If you are experiencing the above warning, try making the override more specific (*assuming your Storybook installation uses webpack5*):

```json
"webpack@5/enhanced-resolve": "5.10.0"
```

(Thanks to Github user **pm0u**)

Answer (score 0):

if you get "property not allowed in package.json", you can use `npm i enhanced-resolve@5.10.0` and then try "npm run storybook". It will work.